# Apply css to all elements except first one with same class name

Tags: html, css

I have below html structure, I want to apply border css to all elements with class name **flw__subform-instance** except first one:

```
<div class="flw__subform__content-wrapper">
    <div class="flw__subform__header"></div>
    <div class="flw__subform-instance">1</div> <!--exclude this bc 1st element -->
    <div class="flw__subform-instance">2</div>
    <div class="flw__subform-instance">3</div>
</div>
```

I have tried below code but its not working:

```
.flw__subform-instance{
    padding: 20px;
    border-top: 1em solid #ddd;
}
.flw__subform-instance:first-child {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short and simple:

```css
.flw__subform-instance ~ .flw__subform-instance {}
```

Reference: [General sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators#general_sibling_combinator)

Try it:

```css
div > div {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #ff0;
}

.foo ~ .foo {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="baz">.baz</div>
  <div class="foo">.foo</div>
  <div class="foo">.foo</div>
  <div class="baz">.baz</div>
  <div class="foo">.foo</div>
  <div class="foo">.foo</div>
  <div class="baz">.baz</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flw__subform-instance{
    padding: 20px;
    border-top: 1em solid #ddd;
}
.flw__subform-instance:first-child {
    padding: 20px;
}

.flw__subform__content-wrapper div:nth-child(2){
    padding: 0px;
    border-top: 0em solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flw__subform__content-wrapper">
    <div class="flw__subform__header"></div>
    <div class="flw__subform-instance">1</div> <!--exclude this bc 1st element -->
    <div class="flw__subform-instance">2</div>
    <div class="flw__subform-instance">3</div>
</div>
```

You can use [nth-child](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector to reset the css of  1st element  which is the second of the wrapper to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
.flw__subform__content-wrapper .flw__subform-instance:not(.flw__subform-instance:nth-of-type(2)) {border:1px solid #000000;}
```